# Some probability density problems.

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

[image]

[image]

*(Note: These are questions from previous semester quizzes etc., which I am practising for an upcoming test. So they are like homework but not actually homework. I've done many of such variety and got them right. These are the ones I couldnt get right. Thanks)*

Comment: Did you work out the problems and get a wrong answer? If you show your work, I bet someone could point out the errors.

Comment: I could not try these because I dont know how to do them. As in, the other questions I tried had no ranges, they had direct values, for eg., f(x) = 0.04x, (x=1,2,3,4,5). In such a case, I can make a distribution table where I have x, and f(x), and then using those values I an find mean, E(x) and variance easily. But in this case, its given a range and I dont know how to make a distribution of x and f(x) out of it. esp, when the range is like between 0 to 1, and not including 0 or 1... *confused*

Comment: There are a great many.  it would take a few pages. Most of them are routine integrations. I will start by doing one. Then perhaps you can try some of the rest using a similar method. If you indicate something you have no idea how to start on, I can perhaps look at it. You should have something in $10$ minutes or so.

Comment: wow! you're always so responsive and helpful. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: But im not sure if these are questions which take pages to solve, I mean the other similar ones in the same question without the ranges took like half a page and all. And they are like foundation level questions, so Im not sure if they would give questions in a test that would take pages..

Comment: The one I was doing was already done, so you should indicate which single problem you want me to do. Or maybe not, someone else is handling it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For number 12:

d.)  Since we are dealing with a continuous Random Variable, and not a discrete Random Variable, the equation for finding the mean is given as:

$$
EX = \int_0^1 xf(x) dx\,.
$$

Before we move forward in actually evaluating this integral, notice that the limits of integration were chosen precisely because it is the range of values of x over which the pdf has positive value. Everywhere outside (0,1) has a pdf value of zero. Now, once we plug in our expression for f(x), this becomes a trivial integral to evaluate.

$$
EX = \int_0^1x(2(1-x))dx = \int_0^1 x(2-2x)dx = \int_0^12x - 2x^2 dx = 1/3
$$

Now that we have our Mean, we can move forward in determining the variance. Recall that the variance of a continuous Random Variable is given as:

$$
Var(X) = \int_0^1(x-EX)^2f(x)dx
$$

You might be tempted to try and plug in our initial integral for calculating EX into this equation, but before you do, remember that EX is constant, and we have already determined its value to be 1/3. Therefore, the integral simplifies to:

$$
Var(X) = \int_0^1(x-1/3)^2f(x)dx = \int_0^1(x^2-2x/3 + 1/9)(2-2x)dx 
$$

Evaluating this integral provides you with the answer of:

$$
Var(X) = 1/18
$$

Now, this process is exactly the same moving forward to parts e and f in this problem. All that remains is for you to set up the integral correctly and evaluate it. Next problems coming soon.

### For question a) following question 12 part f:

Here, again, you are given a continuous pdf, and asked to find the mean and variance not of X, but of a function g(x). This is still pretty straightforward; it all depends on how you set up the problem. First things first, you'll need to find the mean and variance of X before you can go any further. Following the guidelines above, you should be able to set up:

$$
EX = \int_1^2 x(2(x-1))dx = \int_1^2 (2x^2 - 2x) dx = 5/3
$$

$$
Var(X) = \int_1^2 (x-5/3)^2(2x-2)dx = 1/18
$$

Now that we have the mean and variance of X, we can now go about evaluating the mean and variance of g(x). Let's start with the mean. We defined g(x) = 2x + 9. Logically, the mean of X is constant and unchanging. Therefore, if we have a new random variable (g) that multiplies X by 2 and adds 9, it stands to reason that the mean of g is simply the mean of x multiplied by 2 with 9 added on. Therefore,

$$
EG = 2(EX) + 9 = 2(5/3) + 9 = 37/3
$$

Now the variance of G is slightly more difficult to calculate, but not if you have knowledge of this little fact:

#### If a random variable X is adjusted by multiplying by the value b and adding the value a, then the variance is affected as follows:

$$
Var(a+bX) = b^2Var(X)
$$

Armed with this fact, we can now state that the variance of g(x) = 2x + 9 is:

$$
Var(g) = 2^2 Var(X) = 4Var(X) = 2/9
$$

And there you have it; the mean and variance of a function of a Random Variable X.

### For the final problem:

#### Part a: Find the value of "a"

This can be done entirely by knowing the Law of Total Probability. It essentially states that all the probabilities for a particular RV must sum to 1. In terms of a continuous pdf, this equates to:

$$
\int_0^2 f(x)dx = 1
$$

By plugging in our f(x), we find that:

$$
\int_0^2 (a-1/2(x-1)^2)dx = \int_0^2 adx - 1/2\int_0^2(x-1)^2dx
$$

Evaluating this integral and setting it equal to 1 provides the result that a = 2/3.

#### Part b: Find the Mean and Variance of X

This is just a regurgitation of what we have done for the first problem. Set up your integrals correctly and you should have:

$$
EX = \int_0^2 x(2/3-1/2(x-1)^2)dx = 1
$$

$$
Var(X) = \int_0^2 (x-1)^2(2/3-1/2(x-1)^2)dx = 11/45
$$

#### Part C: Estimate P(|x-EX|<1/2)

This last part can be tricky, but just start with what you know. First of all, you know that EX = 1, so start by plugging that straight into the probability expression you are looking for. We now have,

$$
P(|x-1|<1/2) = ?
$$

Next, observe that the pdf of X has positive values only over the range (0,2). Thus, X is always positive, and all of its values are between 0 and 2. This means that the expression |x-1| can range from a value of 0 (when x = 1) to a value of 1 (when x = 0 or x = 2). The issue at hand is to calculate the probability that |x-1| is less than 1/2. See what you can come up with.

Comment: Thnx. I think I can handle e and f alrdy now.

Comment: Good to hear. Let me know if anything is unclear.